# Zip files without compression

Tags: compression, zip

I'd like to bundle a number of big files into a single file, to make them easier to share. The files are already compressed (eg. jpeg, video etc), so I don't need compression, only archiving. How can I put them in a zip file without using zip's compression feature? I don't want to waste time trying to compress gigabytes of already compressed files.

I want to use zip and not `tar` file because many Windows users can't open those files.

Comment: Which program are you using?

Comment: Just a FYI, even those those files have been compressed, you can probably reduce the total size in a compressed archive.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The ZIP format has always supported archiving files with zero compression ratio, even since `pkzip`/`pkunzip` in DOS times.

Nowadays, almost all compression programs support this; [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is one of them, it lets you specify the compression ratio both from the GUI and from the command line, and it's free.

Comment: in 7zip, the 'store' compression option should do the trick

Comment: On OS X, `zip -Z store foo.zip a b c` or `zip -0 foo.zip a b c` will archive `a`, `b`, and `c` without compressing them.

Comment: @IanDunn's comment or @JasomDotnet's answer (`zip -0` or `zip -Z`) should be considered correct answers.

Answer (score 57):

For Linux this shell command zips `mydir` folder with no compression:

```
zip -0 -r mydir.zip mydir
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using WinZip
Go to the "Settings" ribbon, and look for the "zip" group:

[image]

*After* that, drag the files you want to zip, into the file area.
A popup shows that the files have not been compressed in size:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Info-ZIP's zip](http://www.info-zip.org/Zip.html), which is open source, free, and already installed on most Unixish systems has a `-0` option to store only.

Also if you simply zip with any zipper and the entries would be shorter stored than compressed, which is what happens with already compressed files, then they will be stored automagically.  However if you already know they're compressed, then it's faster to just tell zip to do that with `-0`.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on all the files you want to zip, from the menu go to "send to" then click "compressed file".

Comment: This assumes a program to zip files is even installed, which may or may not be true.

Comment: @IvoFlipse: This is built-in Windows functionality.

Comment: It is, but it does use compression.

Comment: The title specifically says "Without compression"

Answer (score 0):

Almost all modern compression tools detect if files are already compressed, and chose not to compress such files.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [B1 Free Archiver](http://b1.org) - it supports zip format perfectly. 
After clicking on "Create archive" just hit the button "More options" and choose "Store". It only stores the files as a single file without compressing them.

Answer (score 0):

Using the zip command, you can supply a specific list of extensions to store without compression. That way you don't waste time (re-)compressing your media files, but you still get the benefits of compression for raw files in the same archive.

The flag is `-n`, and it takes a colon-separated list of extensions. E.g.

```bsh
zip -n .gz:.mp4:.jpg -r mydir.zip mydir
```

There is a default list of stored files; according to the man page on my linux box:

> By default, zip  does  not  compress files with  extensions in the list .Z:.zip:.zoo:.arc:.lzh:.arj

You can also specify a new default list using the `ZIPOPT` environment variable. E.g., under bash:

```bsh
export ZIPOPT="-n .gz:.mp4:.jpg:.zip:.gif"
```

To completely disable this behaviour, including the default list of extensions, use an empty list consisting of a colon: `zip -n : -r ...`.